# Change javascript variable in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a video website, and in the source I have a javascript variable named ajax_switch.post_status which has 2 values, on or off.

Also I have a slide button with 2 options on and off. This button turn on or off publish to facebook. So when I press play to a video after 10 seconds publish to facebook. The button is a jquery one so when I press on or off made a update in database. How can I change the variable of ajax_switch.post_status in real time in source so if the user access the video page and will deactivate the facebook post without refreshing click play to not publish?

I use this in wordpress. My functions are:

Show the button code in single php

```
<div class="left" id="1"></div>
<div id="ajax" style="padding-left: 10px; line-height: 13px; height: 27px; vertical-align:middle; display: table-cell;" >
    Permiteți Video Best să distribuie acest video pe Facebook cu acordul dvs. Debifând această casetă va opri distribuirea și va șterge postarea de pe cronologia dvs.
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#1').iphoneSwitch(ajax_switch.post_status, function() 
    {
        $.post(ajax_switch.templateUrl+'on.php', function(data) 
        {
            $('#ajax').html(data);
            ajax_switch.post_status = 'on';
        });
    },
    function() 
    {
        $.post(ajax_switch.templateUrl+'off.php', function(data) 
        {
            $('#ajax').html(data);
            ajax_switch.post_status = 'off';
        });
    },
    {
        switch_on_container_path: ajax_switch.templateUrl+'iphone_switch_container_off.png'
    });
</script>
```

And the condition for posting:

```
if(ajax_switch.post_status == 'on') 
{
    FB.api(
        '/me/video.watches',
        'post',
        { 
            'movie': '<?php  the_permalink() ?>?ex=257957417674441',
            'access_token': '<?php echo $token; ?>' 
        },
        function(response) 
        {
            if (!response || response.error) 
            {
                console.log(response.error);
            } 
            else 
            {
                console.log('Ewww!');
            }
        });
        }
```

Comment: I guess you could move `ajax_switch.post_status = 'on';` outside of the ajax callback. Maybe I'm not understanding your question though.

Comment: This is perfect, I didn`t thought this will work and I didn`t try it but works. You may answer to this question to give you a vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have your code written currently you have to wait for your ajax request to response before you are updating `ajax_switch.post_status`.

Moving the code outside of the ajax callback will allow it to act immediately with out delay from your database.

Something to keep in mind though, you may want to keep some code in the callback to maintain proper state of your database to the front end client. You can assume that the update successes, but you may want to make a check inside the callback just in case it fails. This way your client is never out of sync with your database.

Comment: Yes I did exactly like this: `$.post(ajax_switch.templateUrl+'on.php', function(data) {
  $('#ajax').html(data);
  ajax_switch.post_status = 'on';
});`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the method "iphoneSwitch" does.  I would expect something like:

```
$("#1").click(function(){
  var targetString = ajax_switch.post_status;
  $.post(ajax_switch.templateUrl + targetString + '.php', function(data) {
    $('#ajax').html(data);   
    ajax_switch.post_status = ajax_switch.post_status == 'off' ? "on" : "off";
  });
});
```

Let me know if there was more to the question than that.

Comment: From here I got the script: http://papermashup.com/jquery-iphone-style-ajax-switch/ . Travis got me the right answer, I tested and worked.